# Its possible to handle 400 bad request using PHP?

Tags: php

I have PHP API which accepting $_GET data.
For Example MY URL is

```
https://example.com/api.php?email=abc@example.com&fname=MyName
```

one of my client is posting data and its working fine but when he have fname with white space like My Name,

```
https://example.com/api.php?email=abc@example.com&fname=My Name
```

its causing 400 BAD Request error.

I have asked him to use URL encode when sending data and problem got solved but he was not agree to use URL encoding and was asking me to fix issue in MY API and in MY SERVER.

As I know, We can not handle such case by Changing MY Api code or by SERVER.

> My Question is its possible that if He send data without encoding and
> I can fix it From PHP API or using Server and so he can not get 400
> BAD request?

Thanks!

Comment: they would get that response if they are specifically building the HTTP request incorrectly i.e fsockopen `GET /api.php?email=abc@example.com&fname=My Name HTTP/1.1` etc, tell them to urlencode the parameter values or use curl file_get_contents etc

Comment: What value  of `fname` did you get in your server? Is it `My` or `My%20Name` or `My+Name` or `My Name`? What's causing the `400` status code?

Comment: @yqlim, My Server giving response called 400 bad request and I am not getting any error log

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have already asked him to use url encode and its get fixed but my question is that if he don't use url encode method, can I add something in my php code or in server which can fix the issue?

Comment: the server is responding with the correct error `GET /?a=b c d e f FOO BAR BAZ HTTP/1.1` is just wrong no matter what your client says, if they are building a custom request they should know this, maybe they are mistaken in thinking percent encoding is not needed on params because if they use curl or fgc or some other lib or browser it will encode it automatically but not if you make a custom socket request you need follow the protocol

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4.2

Comment: _"but he was not agree to use URL encoding"_ - then they are basically saying that they don't want to speak HTTP with your API. So let them make a different suggestion then :-)